# Lenovo MIIX 300-10iby Touchscreen rotation, and charging issue

Tags: power-management, lenovo, touchscreen, display-rotation

I am new in Linux environment, but i know some stuff.
I've just installed Ubuntu 19.04 Desktop on my Lenovo MIIX 300 and it got issues with screen rotation.
I've **removed iio-sensor-proxy** and to rotate my screen i'm using `xrandr` command in terminal.
Very soon I've found that my Touchscreen is not working properly so tried to change some values in `xinput` but nothing happened no matter what values i tried to set.
Here is my [xinput list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rH4bS.jpg) and I used this line:

```
xinput set-prop X "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" <values>
```

> For X equal to 2, 4 or 13

Nothing happened, nothing have changed.
I'm curious to see which prop values i need to change.
This list above was made with keyboard dock unplugged, so you can see only the inputs included in the tablet part.

I recently found out, that even with the **iio-sensor-proxy** touch screen **does not work properly**.
**It works only in one position**, as always (in 'normal')

I've also problem with charging, sometimes Ubuntu shows the charging icon, sometimes not, but there's always sound when i plug and unplug the charging cable. It's not that important as problem above, because it charges properly when system is off.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem with my Miix 300! I managed to find a script online which I modified to help me with this. It is not perfect by any means (auto rotation still does not work [yet])

Save file as Display.sh (or whatever you want really!)

chmod +x display.sh

./display.sh normal/left/right/inverted

You can also add this script to be executed upon login with GDM/lightdm - especially useful with autologin due to GDM/lightdm still being in portrait mode until script is executed after login

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# rotate_desktop.sh
#
# Rotates modern Linux desktop screen and input devices to match. Handy for
# convertible notebooks. Call this script from panel launchers, keyboard
# shortcuts, or touch gesture bindings (xSwipe, touchegg, etc.).
#
# Using transformation matrix bits taken from:
#   https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/InputCoordinateTransformation
#

# Configure these to match your hardware (names taken from `xinput` output).
TOUCHPAD='SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'
TOUCHSCREEN='FTSC1000:00 2808:1015'

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
  echo "Missing orientation."
  echo "Usage: $0 [normal|inverted|left|right] [revert_seconds]"
  echo
  exit 1
fi

function do_rotate
{
  xrandr --output $1 --rotate $2

  TRANSFORM='Coordinate Transformation Matrix'

  case "$2" in
    normal)
 #     [ ! -z "$TOUCHPAD" ]    && xinput set-prop "$TOUCHPAD"    "$TRANSFORM" 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
      [ ! -z "$TOUCHSCREEN" ] && xinput set-prop "$TOUCHSCREEN" "$TRANSFORM" 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
      ;;
    inverted)
#      [ ! -z "$TOUCHPAD" ]    && xinput set-prop "$TOUCHPAD"    "$TRANSFORM" -1 0 1 0 -1 1 0 0 1
      [ ! -z "$TOUCHSCREEN" ] && xinput set-prop "$TOUCHSCREEN" "$TRANSFORM" -1 0 1 0 -1 1 0 0 1
      ;;
    left)
#      [ ! -z "$TOUCHPAD" ]    && xinput set-prop "$TOUCHPAD"    "$TRANSFORM" 0 -1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
      [ ! -z "$TOUCHSCREEN" ] && xinput set-prop "$TOUCHSCREEN" "$TRANSFORM" 0 -1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
      ;;
    right)
#      [ ! -z "$TOUCHPAD" ]    && xinput set-prop "$TOUCHPAD"    "$TRANSFORM" 0 1 0 -1 0 1 0 0 1
      [ ! -z "$TOUCHSCREEN" ] && xinput set-prop "$TOUCHSCREEN" "$TRANSFORM" 0 1 0 -1 0 1 0 0 1
      ;;
  esac
}

XDISPLAY=`xrandr --current | grep primary | sed -e 's/ .*//g'`
XROT=`xrandr --current --verbose | grep primary | egrep -o ' (normal|left|inverted|right) '`

do_rotate $XDISPLAY $1

if [ ! -z "$2" ]; then
  sleep $2
  do_rotate $XDISPLAY $XROT
  exit 0
fi
```